# Do you need to include copy over other files from "values" when supporting multiple languages?

Tags: android, internationalization, android-resources

I read on [Android Developers' Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs)
that in order for your application to support multiple language, you have to make multiple values folder inside your "res" folder - "values", "values-es", "values-fr". Say in your original English "values" folder you also had `colors.xml`, and `dimens.xml`, would you need to copy those over into each language "values" folder?

The document only says

> At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.

which I interpreted as "Android will use strings.xml from the right folder".

If you could, I think it would be good to reduce redundancy if you only have `colors.xml` and `dimens.xml` in one folder(all the others could share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a separate file (strings.xml, colors.xml, dimen.xml etc.) if you want to override the default values (in the values folder). Usually colors and dimensions are language independent so there's no need to create those files in the language specific folders.

Comment: so it only searches for strings.xml, not other files

Comment: No Android does search for other files but if they are not found in the language specific folders (like values-fr), Android will use the ones in the values folder. That means you only need to create the language specific files if you want to override the default values in the "values" folder which is usually not necessary for dimensions and colors.

Answer (score 1):

Android will first search for values in the folder of the current language, that means if language is french it will first search in `values-fr`. If it doesn't find it there it will go to the default `values` folder.

This does not only apply to `colors.xml` and other files, it also applies to strings inside `string.xml`. If a string is the same in english and in another language (if it's a name for example) just don't include the translated string and it will choose the default one.